# mean() warning: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns. When I try to calculate `mean`, I get this message:

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(results) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`
```

where 'results' is my data set. Any advice on getting around this problem?

Comment: We need more information, please.  http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 , or at least the results of `str()` on your data frame.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

From R 3.0.0 onwards `mean(<data.frame>)` is defunct (and passing a data.frame to `mean` will give the error you state)

> A data frame is a list of variables of the same number of rows with unique row names, given class "data.frame".

In your case, result has two variables (if your description is correct) . You could obtain the column means by using any of the following

```
lapply(results, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
sapply(results, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
colMeans(results, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: In that case shouldn't by() documentation be updated to prevent annoying errors with by(dt, index, mean) when the documentation specifically says dt can be a data frame?

Answer (score 21):

If you just want to know the mean, you can use

```
summary(results)
```

It will give you more information than expected.

ex) Mininum value, 1st Qu., Median, Mean, 3rd Qu. Maxinum value, number of NAs.

Furthermore, If you want to get mean values of each column, you can simply use the method below.

```
mean(results$columnName, na.rm = TRUE)
```

That will return mean value. (you have to change 'columnName' to your variable name

Comment: Running `mean(results$columnName, na.rm = TRUE)` with my dataset and variables in my R code still throws the same error `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Answer (score 1):

The same error appears if you do not use the correct (numeric) format of your data in your data.frame column using `mean()` function. Therefore, check your data using `str(data.frame&column)` function to see what data type you have, and convert it to numeric format if necessary.
For example, if your data is Character convert it with `as.numeric(data.frame$column)`, or as a factor with `as.numeric(as.character(data.frame$column))`. The mean function does not work with types other than numeric.