# Calculating mean absolute error with a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two datasets `Shuffle_W` and `Volume_W`. I want to get the MAE error based on certain calculations. Dataset `Shuffle_W` has the shuffle order and dataset `Volume_W`has the Volume details for each part.

```
Shuffle_W <- data.frame(C1 = c(Ar, Ba, Ca, Ba, Bu), 
                        C2 = c(Bu, Bu, Bu, Bu, Ar), 
                        C3 = c(Bl, Bl, Ba, Bl, Ca), 
                        C4 = c(Ca, Ar, Bl, Ar, Bl), 
                        C5 = c(Ba, Ca, Ar, Ca, Ba))

Volume <- data.frame(Ar = c(-5.1275, -2.2385, -5.3705, -6.4925, -5.068), 
                     Ba = c(1.3465, 1.5065, 1.1285, 1.5735, 0.9455), 
                     Bl = c(-1.544, 0.193, 1.966, 1.36, 0.947), 
                     Bu = c(-0.0877, 1.082, 1.183, -0.0761, -0.7775), 
                     Ca = c(3.2955, 3.074, -1.9305, 2.0875, 3.832))
```

After doing a shuffle matching the elements from both datasets, I want to find the MAE error at each step of the shuffle. I use the following code.

```
Total_Volume <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 1))
print(Total_Volume)
Total_MAE <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 5))
print(Total_MAE)
for (a in 1:5)
{
  Total_Volume = 0
  Volume_Temp = 0
  for (b in 1:5)
  {
    j <- match(Shuffle_W[a, b], names(Volume_W))
    Volume_Temp = Volume[j]
    Total_Volume = Volume_Temp + Total_Volume
    print(Total_Volume)
    #This is step by step process of calculating MAE
    #sample_abs = abs(Total_Volume)
    #print(sample_abs)
    #sample_mae = mean(as.numeric(sample_abs))
    #print(sample_mae)
    #Ends here
    MAE_Value = mean(abs(Total_Volume), na.rm = TRUE)
    print(MAE_Value)
    MAE_Value = MAE_Value + MAE_Initial
    Total_MAE[a, b] = MAE_Value
  }
  print(Total_MAE)
}
```

Separately calculating MAE (This works fine)

```
sample_MAE_Ar = mean(abs(Volume_W$Ar), na.rm = TRUE)
print(sample_MAE_Ar)
```

I am not able to calculate the MAE in a loop. When I tried calculating the MAE using the formula directly it gives the error:

```
In mean.default(abs(Total_Volume), na.rm = TRUE) 
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

So when I tried breaking down the formula it seems to calculate the absolute value without any problem but gets stuck when calculating the mean. I even tried using the type conversion of `as.numeric` but still doesn't work. I only get the error

```
Error in mean(as.numeric(sample_abs)) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I am not sure what the issue is cause the same works fine when done separately. I am not sure if it is due to the for loop. Any help in this regard is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the way you're extracting your column from the data frame. These two lines

```
j <- match(Shuffle_W[a, b], names(Volume_W))
Volume_Temp = Volume[j]
```

results in a data frame but the `mean` function expects a vector. Either you should convert `Volume_Temp` to a vector or use `sapply` together with `mean`. See if the following works:

```
Total_MAE <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 5))
print(Total_MAE)
for (a in 1:5)
{
  Total_Volume = 0
  Volume_Temp = 0
  MAE_Initial = 0
  for (b in 1:5)
  {
    j <- match(Shuffle_W[a, b], names(Volume_W))
    Volume_Temp = Volume[j][[1]]  # Extract the first element of the list here
    Total_Volume = Volume_Temp + Total_Volume
    print(Total_Volume)
    #This is step by step process of calculating MAE
    #sample_abs = abs(Total_Volume)
    #print(sample_abs)
    #sample_mae = mean(as.numeric(sample_abs))
    #print(sample_mae)
    #Ends here
    MAE_Value = mean(abs(Total_Volume), na.rm = TRUE)
    print(MAE_Value)
    MAE_Value = MAE_Value + MAE_Initial
    Total_MAE[a, b] = MAE_Value
  }
  print(Total_MAE)
}
```

You haven't provided all the info for a reproducible example (`MAE_Initial` is not found, and `Shuffle_W` and `Volume_W` is not well-defined R code) but I'm pretty sure that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code works fine. I have added the MAE_Initial value to the code. As far as Shuffle_W and Volume_W is concerned they are actually files that have been extracted from a database and I tried to make them reproducible for this question. I tried to create them myself and I have not done a great job at it.

Comment: Also a previous post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697498/r-beginner-argument-is-not-numeric-or-logical-returning-na?lq=1) explains why i get the error. It is cause after ver 3.0.0 mean cannot be used directly on a column and as you rightfully suggested i should try use one of the apply functions or just colMeans which also works. Code : MAE_Value = colMeans(abs(Total_Volume), na.rm = TRUE)
    MAE_Value = MAE_Value + MAE_Initial
    Total_MAE[a, b] = MAE_Value. This snippet also worls fine.

Comment: Yeah using `colMeans` is probably cleaner. Glad it's working