# Why I receive this message when using a replacement function? In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I'm playing a bit with  [replacement functions in R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#special-calls) and made this simple function which modifies a value for the vector's mean. It works perfectly on a single vector:

```
'value.for.mean<-' <- function(x, value, ...) {
    x[value] = mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
    x
}

x <- c(1:3,NA, 2:5,1:10, NA, NA)
value.for.mean(x) <- is.na(x)
x   

#Output:    
[1]  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.41  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  1.00  2.00  3.00  4.00
[13]  5.00  6.00  7.00  8.00  9.00 10.00  4.41  4.41
```

When I try to use the same function with a data.frame I got the error:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1,3,NA,4,2), b=c(9,8,5,4,NA))
value.for.mean(x) <- is.na(x)
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
>   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> ```

I read many threads in SO which refer to that error but no one points to this specific case since my variables are numeric as you can see when calling `str(x)`

```
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  1 3 NA 4 2
 $ b: num  9 8 5 4 NA
```

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Related: [mean(): argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697498/mean-argument-is-not-numeric-or-logical-returning-na)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mean` works on `vector`.  According to `?mean`, the usage is

```
mean(x, ...)
```

where

> x - An R object. Currently there are methods for numeric/logical
>   vectors and date, date-time and time interval objects.

So, when we apply `mean` on the whole `data.frame`, it gives the same warning message as in the OP's post because the OP's function is a wrapper around `mean`

```
mean(x)
#[1] NA
```

> Warning message: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or
>   logical: returning NA

---

We need to loop through the columns and apply the function, return the column and update the `list` of `vector`s back to the original dataset

```
x[] <- lapply(x, function(y) {
              value.for.mean(y) <- is.na(y)
               y})
```

Or applying it with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% 
    mutate_all(funs({value.for.mean(.) <- is.na(.); .}))
```

Here

Comment: Thank you so much. Very clear and informative. Happy 2019! :)

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera  Glad to know that it helped.  Happy New Year!